# EF code-first to create local database in ASP.NET MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. While going through this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I am getting error

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 123 (the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\AMIT & AKASH\ContosoUniversity2 AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|_ContosoUniversity2.mdf.mdf'.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

My connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v12.0;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity2 AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ContosoUniversity2.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**SchoolInitializer.cs**

[image]

**StudentContext.cs**

[image]

Comment: Don't post code as images, we prefer text that can be googled.

Comment: next time for sure on my mind :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely just forgot a **semicolon** after specifying the initial catalog:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v12.0;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity2;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ContosoUniversity2.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So change:

```
Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity2
```

to

```
Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity2;
                                  ^
                                  |
                     add this semicolon!
```